# Adaptive card extension (ACE) spfx remove sharepoint logo

Tags: adaptive-cards

I'm devoloping adaptive card and customer ask if is possible to remove sharepoint logo (icon) in upper left corner.. I didn't find a way how to do it, can someone help?

thx!

tried to search over the internet..

Answer (score 0):

To change the top left adaptive card logo:
Open the cardview json file (-solutionname-adaptivecardextension.manifest.json) and replace the value of "officeFabricIconFontName". You should paste the image url you are using: "officeFabricIconFontName":"httpsimagelinkhere", refresh the workbench, delete the ACE and re-add it to see changes.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I know ho to change the logo, I should have been clearer - I need to remove it completely. There is posibility to change it by white square  or something similar, but in this case the text is indented as if there was an icon.